# Remove duplicate numbers next to each other in json by javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My json:

```
{ "question_1": 
  { "type"  : "string"
  , "title" : "1. 1. What did he want to make for dinner?"
  , "enum": 
    [ " a.) He wanted to make some salad and spaghetti"
    , " b.) He wanted to make some pasta salad"
    ] 
  , "required": false
  } 
, "question_2": 
  { "type": "string"
  , "title": "2. 2. Did he have the ingredients to make dinner?"
  , "enum": 
    [ " a.) Yes, he had the ingredients"
    , " b.) No, he didn't have the ingredients"
    ] 
  , "required": false
  } 
, "question_3": 
  { "type"  : "string"
  , "title" : "3. 3. Where did he go shopping?"
  , "enum": 
    [ " a.) He went to Albertsons"
    , " b.) He went to Albertos"
    ] 
  , "required": false
  } 
}
```

in my json there are many numbers next to each other and are duplicated

Eg:

```
1. 1. => 1.
2. 2. => 2.
3. 3. => 3.
```

and so on

How can i remove this duplication?

I want to remove duplicate numbers next to each other in json

Comment: That doesn't look like JSON (which would be a String), it looks like a JavaScript Object literal. But, that aside, what's generating the duplication of numbers, can that be fixed instead of tidying up after the fact?

Comment: @DavidThomas, no, it is a valid JSON. you can use any inline JSON validator to check it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace it using a regex. Using grouping references (the parenthesis around `(\d)` form a group of one decimal and the `\1` refers to it) will make sure that you don't remove numbers like "1. 2." and allow you to refer to it during replacement:

```js
const data =
  { "question_1": 
    { "type"  : "string"
    , "title" : "1. 1. What did he want to make for dinner?"
    , "enum": 
      [ " a.) He wanted to make some salad and spaghetti"
      , " b.) He wanted to make some pasta salad"
      ] 
    , "required": false
    } 
  , "question_2": 
    { "type": "string"
    , "title": "2. 2. Did he have the ingredients to make dinner?"
    , "enum": 
      [ " a.) Yes, he had the ingredients"
      , " b.) No, he didn't have the ingredients"
      ] 
    , "required": false
    } 
  , "question_3": 
    { "type"  : "string"
    , "title" : "3. 3. Where did he go shopping?"
    , "enum": 
      [ " a.) He went to Albertsons"
      , " b.) He went to Albertos"
      ] 
    , "required": false
    } 
  };

Object.values(data).forEach(v => v.title = v.title.replace(/(\d)\. \1\./, '$1.'))
console.log(Object.values(data).map(v => v.title))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it actually is JSON, which you are going to parse using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), you could make use of the optional `reviver` parameter.

> ## reviver
>
> If a function, this prescribes how each value originally produced by
> parsing is transformed before being returned. Non-callable values are
> ignored. The function is called with the following arguments:
>
> ### key
>
> The key associated with the value.
>
> ### value
>
> The value produced by parsing.

```js
const JSONString = `{
  "question_1": {
    "type": "string",
    "title" : "1. 1. What did he want to make for dinner?"
  },
  "question_2": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "2. 2. Did he have the ingredients to make dinner?"
  } 
}`;

console.log(
  JSON.parse(JSONString, (key, value) => typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/(\d)\. \1\./, '$1.') : value)
)
```

Expanding on Moritz Ringler's solution.